# Member variable of subtype of base class in base class

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way to do the following with templates?   The following code throws unknown type compile time errors.

I'm trying to create two different types of Application, those that inherit from Application, and those that inherit from Service, which inherits from Application. All Applications have one service called Cron, which will inherit from Service. Applications will be threaded and detached, while Services that derive from Application will be threaded and joined. I broke this down to simplest terms.

```
#include <iostream>

class Application
{
public:
Service service; //Throws unknown type... Forward decl. will not work either.

};


class Service:public Application
{


};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

// insert code here...
std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
return 0;
}
```

Thanks,

Bruce

Comment: The moment `Service` inherited from `Application`, which has a member of type `Service`, this no longer made sense. What are really trying to do, and *why* ?

Comment: If `Application` contains a `Service` which is part `Application` which contains a `Service` which is part `Application`... where do you stop? How big is an `Application` object?

Comment: I'm trying to create two different types of Application, those that inherit from Application, and those that inherit from Service, which inherits from Application.   All Applications have one service called Cron, which will inherit from Service.    Applications will be threaded and detached, while Services that derive from Application will be threaded and joined.   I broke this down to simplest terms.

Comment: @cresanta *that* comment is fairly well presented and honestly belongs in your *question*. Whether there is a way to *accomplish* that remains to be seen, but those details are *very* relevant.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, and there's probably a better way, but you can make it work with forward declaration and a pointer member instead of value member.

Comment: @cresanta: Do you mean that "all applications will *share* one service called Cron"  e.g. `class Application { static Service Cron; };` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to do what you want, because what you want to do is *nonsense.*  Hold on, I'll explain.

`Service` is derived from `Application`, but `Application` has a member of type `Service`.

This is a cyclic dependancy but beyond that, I just don't understand it.  Since `Service` is derived from `Application`, which has a member of type `Service`, which is derived from `Application`, which has a member of type `Service`... you get the idea.   It's like standing in front of a mirror with a mirror and trying to find the end.

Now the question becomes, what are you *really* trying to do?

In your comments, you said:

> I'm trying to create two different types of Application, those that
>   inherit from Application, and those that inherit from Service, which
>   inherits from Application. All Applications have one service called
>   Cron, which will inherit from Service.

There's still a little ambiguity here.  How can Application derive from Application?

I suspect that what you're after is having two different concrete instantiations of the class which implements `Service`.  One only implements `Service`, and the other implements other stuff too.

In that case:

```
class Service
{
public:
  void Cron();
};

class Application
{
public:
  void OtherStuff();
};
```

But you also said:

> Applications will be threaded and detached, while Services that derive
>   from Application will be threaded and joined.

That sounds like a job for a [policy-based design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design).

```
class DetatchedPolicy
{
public:
  void StartThread();  // this function would start the thread and detatch
};

class JoinedPolicy
{
public:
  void StartThread();  // this function would start the thread and join
};

template <typename ThreadingPolicy>
class BasicService
:
  public ThreadingPolicy
{
public:
  Service()
  {
    StartThread();
  }
  void Cron();
};

typedef BasicService <JoinedPolicy> Service;
typedef BasicService <DetatchedPolicy> Application;
```

Comment: It's an infinite recursion.

Comment: Should I break the model into two or more hierarchies and base the ultimate design on composition.   For instance  class ApplicationComposite that contains Applications and Services from two distinct hierarchies?

Comment: John,  The policy-based design method looks the cleanest.   When I wrote this originally, I forgot that classes are different than structs because of inheritance.   It's legal to declare a member of a struct to be the enclosing type, but, of course, there are no inheritance semantics.

Comment: @cresanta:  Huh?  A struct has the same inheritance semantics as a class, except for default visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actually want to do is to use a pointer.

```
class Service;
class Application 
{

     std::shared_ptr<Service> m_service;
};

class Service : public Application
{
};
```

Comment: This is still a cycle.  How can this really be what the OP wants?

Comment: He wants to associate a service with every application. This would allow that. And the pointer doesn't have to point to anything for some terminal case.

Comment: Will this not evoke UB when an instance of `Service` is destroyed?

Comment: Because `this` will be `delete`d twice.

Comment: What are you talking about? m_service would not be pointing to the object which contains it. And I'm *not* trying to give the guy a complete design. I'm trying to show him how he can associate a service with every application.

Comment: I'm talking about m_service pointing to the object which contains it.  Which, apparently, you're not imputing.  Without reading these comments, it's likely OP didn't understand that, either.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you may benefit from separating the interfaces from the implementations:

```
struct ApplicationInterface
{
    virtual ~ApplicationInterface() {}

    virtual void do_application_stuff_1() = 0;
    virtual void do_application_stuff_2() = 0;
};

struct ServiceInterface
: public ApplicationInterface
{
    virtual ~ServiceInterface() {}

    virtual void do_service_stuff_1() = 0;
    virtual void do_service_stuff_2() = 0;
};

class CronService
: ServiceInterface
{
public:
    // ApplicationInterface
    virtual void do_application_stuff_1() {}
    virtual void do_application_stuff_2() {}

    // ServiceInterface
    virtual void do_service_stuff_1() {}
    virtual void do_service_stuff_2() {}
};

class Application
: ApplicationInterface
{
protected:
    CronService cron;

public:

    virtual void do_application_stuff_1() {}
    virtual void do_application_stuff_2() {}
};
```